# How can I assign a range of values to a variable in python

Tags: python-2.7, variable-assignment

I'm programming in python 2.7.9. I need to assign a range of values ​​to a variable.

Example: I need the variable "x" to take the numbers from 0 to 10 (0 > x < 10)(
Including decimals) so that I can compare this variable with another

Comment: x = range(10)  or x = xrange(10)

Comment: This is very basic stuff. An hour or two with a tutorial is well advised. You likely want `for x in range(10): ...` but it depends on the compare you want.

Comment: Ever hear of a for loop and an array?

Comment: I need the variable "x" to take the numbers from 0 to 10 (0 > x < 10)( Including decimals)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements

Answer (score 0):

You can use range or xrange.

Let me show you how it works. If you write `x = range(5)` it will give you a list with elements [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] default start point is 0 and end point is n-1.

If you want the list to be 0

```
x = range(1, 10) # here Default start is 1 and end is less than 10
```

Let me know if you have any other queries.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of doing that:
Most obvious is to use `range(1,10)`
You can get the range of numbers stored in a form of list using:

```
>>>> range_list = [i for i in range(1,10)]
```

For more info: http://pythoncentral.io/pythons-range-function-explained/

The given list can also be generated using numpy as:

```
>>> np.linspace(1,9,9)
array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.])
```

More info: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking is binning the data.
You can use cut method to do that.

```
interval_range = pd.interval_range(start=0, freq=10, end=280)
df['target_range'] = pd.cut(df['total_runs'], bins=interval_range)
```

Comment: I guess it would be helpful to provide a reproducible answer easy to run - the question was quite generic.